# Changin list which is an iput with function

Tags: ocaml

Good morning, 
I have a problem with coding using ocaml so I had to code a function that take on input list then add to this list an element.
But using this does'nt affect the list1 so how can I do this ?
Thank you.

```
  let rec append list1 element list2 = match list2 with 
    []-> list1
    | e::l -> if  ( element = e )  then e :: list1 
              else (append list1 element l)
   ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

List are immutable in OCaml, you can't change this. You can write a function `append` that takes a list and returns a new list that appends an element to it.

For example, here is the `prepend` function that takes a list and an element and returns a new list with the given element prepended to the passed list,

```
let prepend xs x = x :: xs
```

The `append` function is a little bit trickier, since lists in OCaml are singly-linked, so it is easy to prepend but hard to append. To implement the `append` function you need an intermediate list, let's call it `acc` for *accumulator*. You then go through each element of the input list and add it to the accumulator. Since you're prepending, then once the input list is over your accumulator will have all the elements of the input list by in the reversed order, i.e., the first element (aka the head) of the `acc` list will be the last element of the input list. Now you what is left is to prepend the element that we want to append to the reversed `acc` list and reverse act. Here is the skeleton code for you

```
let append xs x = 
   let rec loop xs acc = match xs with
     | ... -> ... in
   loop xs []
```

Comment: So there is no way to change the input list for exemple here if we do print xs it does change or not ?

Comment: How can I finish the function pls ?

        let append xs x = 
        let rec loop xs acc = match xs with
       | e::l -> (prepend acc e ) in
       loop xs []

Comment: yes, the list once created never changes, it is like a constant, e.g., `1` is always one and when you add two numbers, e.g., `1` and `2`, neither you change `1` or `2` but you return a new number `3` that reflects the sum of `1` and `2`. Going back to the lists, when you have `[1;2]` and `[3]` when you concatenate them you produce a new list that reflects their concatenation `[1;2;3]`.